# Changing the color of a subset of Google Maps markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-fusion-tables

I am about to develop a Google Maps application, in which markers will be populated from a table with the following structure (simplified):

```
marker_id (INT)
label (TEXT)
latitude (FLOAT)
longitude (FLOAT)
creation_date (DATE/TIME)
```

The information may be stored in a Fusion table (preferred) or in MySQL.
All markers will be displayed on the map in red.
Next to the map there will be date picker component, and I would like the color of all markers whose creation_date is on the selected date, to change to some other color (say, yellow).
Is there any way I can do this without having to create all the markers on the client side, and saving references to them?
There may be many markers (more than 10K, perhaps up to 100K) so I'm not sure how well this will work on the client-side (which is why I prefer fusion table layers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with a FT Layer via the GMaps API. See [API Docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#fusion_table_styles) for the basics.

```
styles: [{
    where: "creation_date = '4/1/2013' ",
    markerOptions: {
      iconName: "small_yellow"
    }
  },
  {  // default style
    markerOptions: {
     iconName: "small_red"
  } ]
```

With so many markers FT is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: didnt see that you wanted to avoid making references on the client side. AFAIK its impossible to display markers on the google map without creating the markers... perhaps if you run into scalability problems, you can figure out a way to display fewer markers at a time

---

set or change the icons manually as desired:

```
var redIcon = {
  url:'/icons/redIcon.png',
};

var yellowIcon = {
  url:'/icons/yellowIcon.png',
};

// Populate some data structure to associate pins with data
var dataPlusMarkers = [
{ data: 99,  pin: new google.maps.Marker(...) },
{ data: 200, pin: new google.maps.Marker(...) }
];

function setColors(){
  dataPlusMarkers.forEach(function(one){
    if(one.data > 100){ 
      one.pin.setIcon(yellowIcon);
    } else {
      one.pin.setIcon(redIcon);
    }
  });
};
```